# Detect window resize and perform function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make it so that each time when user changes the window size, the page perform a function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following function should do what you need, it works on all browsers (*with the single exception of not firing when Safari is NOT maximized and resolution changes*)

**It fires upon window re-sizing as well as resolution change** and also has a delay to avoid multiple calls while the user is re-sizing the window.

```
    var resizeTimer;

    //Event to handle resizing
    $(window).resize(function () 
    {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(Resized, 100);
    });

    //Actual Resizing Event
    function Resized() 
    {
        //Your function goes here
    };
```

**[Testing jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJK5L/)**

Comment: this needs jquery, isn't it ?

Comment: I feel fairly sure that event will fire if the window is maximized when the resolution change happens, but will it fire if the window isn't maximized and doesn't actually change size?

Comment: @Rick - It might be worth testing

Comment: @Rick - I tested it and it does fire upon resolution change, both maximized and otherwise.

Comment: The question asks about **screen resolution**, and not about the window size.

Comment: @Rionmonster - Interesting... Now I'm curious and I'm going to have to test it with different browsers -- off to JSFiddle I go.  Just curious... what browser did you test with?

Comment: @Rikudo - Yes, we realize that. My question was based on whether or not the resize event would fire if the screen resolution changed but didn't impact the browser. Obviously, if the browser is maximized and the resolution changes, the window size will change. But we weren't sure about the converse...

Comment: @Rick I tested with Chrome, Firefox, IE8 (and Compatability-Mode)

Comment: sorry, i meant window change.

Comment: @Henry - No biggie. This should work for that, as well as resolution changes.

Comment: @Rionmonster - Tested your fiddle with Safari 5.1 on Windows 7 and it works when maximized, but it does NOT work if Safari isn't maximized. That's the behavior I would have expected from all browsers. Anyway, thanks for the interesting after-lunch distraction. :-)

Comment: You can check $(window).width() to figure out if its a maximize or minimize that took place

Answer (score 1):

In regards to this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onresize

```
window.onresize = resize;

function resize()
{
    alert('window size changed');
}
```

window.resize makes it quite simple.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: It's a response. To this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000029/detect-window-resize-and-perform-function-with-jquery/16066164?noredirect=1#comment22930670_16066164

Comment: Ahh, my first time reviewing, I forgot it's an answer not a question. Ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

My proposition. First HTML & CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
        #div1 content
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        #div2 content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    color: white;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 5px 18px;
    font: 700 16px/200% sans-serif;
}
#div1 {
    background-color: #d00;
}
#div2 {
    background-color: #27d;
}
```

Now the **jQuery**:

On document ready only (https://jsfiddle.net/sz7aeo9j/)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var divone = $('#div1')[0].outerHTML
        var divtwo = $('#div2')[0].outerHTML
        $('#div2,#div1').remove();
        if ($(window).width() < 640) {
            $('#div1').remove();
            $('#wrapper').html(divtwo);
        }
        if ($(window).width() > 640) {
            $('#div2').remove();
            $('#wrapper').html(divone);
        }
    });
</script>
```

On window resizing  (https://jsfiddle.net/sz7aeo9j/1/)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var divone = $('#div1')[0].outerHTML
        var divtwo = $('#div2')[0].outerHTML
        $('#div1').remove();
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($(window).width() < 640) {
                $('#div1').remove();
                $('#wrapper').html(divtwo);
            }
            if ($(window).width() > 640) {
                $('#div2').remove();
                $('#wrapper').html(divone);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can register an event onresize on the window : a function is called when window size changed

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize

Answer (score 0):

Use `screen.width` and `screen.height` to determine the width and height of the screen.